# Значения координат оси X графика Chart отображаются выше самой оси

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

[image: Некорректное отображение координат]

У меня есть списки, на основе которых строятся графики в классе Chart. Я задаю название осей следующим образом:

```cs
Axis x = new Axis();
x.Title = "Число автосамосвалов";
Data.infoform.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX = x;
Data.infoform.chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX = x;
Data.infoform.chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX = x;
Data.infoform.chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisX = x;
```

В результате ось Х и её координаты сдвигаются вверх, заползая на сам график. Увеличение размера окоy не помогает. Самое интересное - на четвертом графике ось подписана нормально, хотя он во всём идентичен остальным по коду. Что с этим делать?